# How do I find all tokens in a string that matches regexp in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm wondering how I can extract all tokens matching a regular expression in perl and put them in a list?  I saw a nifty example on stackoverflow, but I can't find it again (argh!!)

So, suppose:

```
my $cppString = "  boost::fancyFunc( widget->dooHicky());"
```

I'd like to be able to extract all \w+ tokens from string.  But, maybe later I might want to just extract all tokens that look like "\w+::\w+", or "\w+->\w".

Anyways, what is the readable compact way of doing this given a regexp?

The example (which I can't find) looked something like this:

```
my @cppTokens = ($cppString =~ m/(regexp)/g);
```

Anyways, the  above example is not exactly right.

thanks.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304577/how-can-i-store-regex-captures-in-an-array-in-perl) ??

Comment: Yes, this is it, thanks for finding it for me.

Comment: How do I remove my own embarassing question?  :)

Comment: :P there must be a link anywhere :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here to make it official:

[The wanted link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304577/how-can-i-store-regex-captures-in-an-array-in-perl)