# How do I grab an unknown number of captures from a pattern?

Tags: regex, perl

Lets say I have a pattern:

```
<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2
```

As you can see, the pattern could have multiple values (in this case pin has 2 sets of pin names). The amount is unknown.

How would I parse this? Here is what I have so far, but it is not helpful as it does not take into account if the pattern has more than 2 sets of pins.

```
my $pattern = "<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";

if ( $pattern =~ m#\<cell\> (\w*=\w*) \<pin\> (\w*=\w*) \<type\> (\w*=\w*)#) {

my $cell_name = $1;
my $pin_name = $2;
my $type_name = $3;
}
```

as you can see, this will only work if there is only one set of pin names. However I want it to be able to adjust to multiple unknown sets of pin names. I think I would have to construct like an array or hash, but I am not really sure what is the best way of grabbing these values taking into account the unknown multiple pin sets.

I would like to be able to store the cell_name,pin_name and type_name as an array or hash with the sets of values.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a bit trickier than [Why do I get the first capture group only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62690858/2766176) but some of those ideas may help. The trick is to stop thinking about doing everything in a single pattern.

If that's really your input, I'd be tempted to match groups of things around an `=`. Matching in list context, such as assigning to a hash, returns the list of matches:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $input = "<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";
my %values = $input =~ m/ (\S+) = (\S+) /gx;

print Dumper( \%values );
```

The things before the `=` become keys and the things after become the values:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'pin1' => 'pin2',
          'type1' => 'type2',
          'cell1' => 'cell2',
          'pin3' => 'pin4'
        };
```

But life probably isn't that easy. The example names probably don't really have `pin`, `cell`, and so on.

There's another thing I like to do, though, because I miss having all that fun with `sscan`. You can walk a string by matching part of it at a time, then on the next match, start where you left off. Here's the whole thing first:

```
use v5.10;

use Data::Dumper;

my $input = "<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";

my %hash;
while( 1 ) {
    state $type;

    if( $input =~ /\G < (.*?) > \s* /xgc ) {
        $type = $1;
        }
    elsif( $input =~ /\G (\S+) = (\S+) \s* /xgc ) {
        $hash{$type}{$1}{$2}++;
        }
    else { last }
    }

print Dumper( \%hash );
```

And the data structure, which really doesn't matter and can be anything that you like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'type' => {
                      'type1' => {
                                   'type2' => 1
                                 }
                    },
          'pin' => {
                     'pin1' => {
                                 'pin2' => 1
                               },
                     'pin3' => {
                                 'pin4' => 1
                               }
                   },
          'cell' => {
                      'cell1' => {
                                   'cell2' => 1
                                 }
                    }
        };
```

But let's talk about his for a moment. First, all of the matches are in scalar context since they are in the conditional parts of the `if-elsif-else` branches. That means they only make the next match.

However, I've anchored the start of each pattern with `\G`. This makes the pattern match at the beginning of the string or the position where the previous successful match left off when I use the `/g` flag in scalar context.

But, I want to try several patterns, so some of them are going to fail. That's where the `/c` flag comes in. It doesn't reset the match position on failure. That means the `\G` anchor won't reset on an unsuccessful match. So, I can try a pattern, and if that doesn't work, start at the same position with the next one.

So, when I encounter something in angle brackets, I remember that type. Until I match another thing in angle brackets, that's the type of thing I'm matching. Now when I match `(\S+) = (\S+)`, I can assign the matches to the right type.

To watch this happen, you can output the remembered string position. Each scalar maintains its own cursor and `pos(VAR)` returns that position:

```
use v5.10;

use Data::Dumper;

my $input = "<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";

my %hash;
while( 1 ) {
    state $type;

    say "Starting matches at " . ( pos($input) // 0 );
    if( $input =~ /\G < (.*?) > \s* /xgc ) {
        $type = $1;
        say "Matched <$type>, left off at " . pos($input);
        }
    elsif( $input =~ /\G (\S+) = (\S+) \s* /xgc ) {
        $hash{$type}{$1}{$2}++;
        say "Matched <$1|$2>, left off at " . pos($input);
        }
    else {
        say "Nothing left to do, left off at " . pos($input);
        last;
        }
    }

print Dumper( \%hash );
```

Before the Dumper output, you now see the global matches in scalar context walk the string:

```
Starting matches at 0
Matched <cell>, left off at 7
Starting matches at 7
Matched <cell1|cell2>, left off at 19
Starting matches at 19
Matched <pin>, left off at 25
Starting matches at 25
Matched <pin1|pin2>, left off at 35
Starting matches at 35
Matched <pin3|pin4>, left off at 45
Starting matches at 45
Matched <type>, left off at 52
Starting matches at 52
Matched <type1|type2>, left off at 63
Starting matches at 63
Nothing left to do, left off at 63
```

---

Finally, as a bonus, here's a recursive decent grammar that does it. It's certainly overkill for what you've provided, but does better in more tricky situations. I won't explain it other than to say it produces the same data structure:

```
use v5.10;

use Parse::RecDescent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $grammar = <<~'HERE';
    startrule: context_pairlist(s)
    context_pairlist: context /\s*/ pair(s)
    context: '<' /[^>]+/ '>'
        { $::context = $item[2] }
    pair: /[A-Za-z0-9]+/ '=' /[A-Za-z0-9]+/
        { main::build_hash( $::context, @item[1,3] ) }
    HERE

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new( $grammar );

my %hash;
sub build_hash {
    my( $context, $name, $value ) = @_;
    $hash{$context}{$name}{$value}++;
    }

my $input = "<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";
$parser->startrule( $input );

say Dumper( \%hash );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have space separated tokens. Some tokens indicate a new scope and some tokens indicate values being set in that scope. I find it most straightforward to just run through the list of tokens in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = q{<cell> cell1=cell2 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2};

my (%h, $k);
while ($s =~ /(\S+)/g) {
    my ($x, $y)= split /=/, $1;

    if (defined $y) {
     push $h{$k}->@*, {key => $x, value => $y};
     next;
    }

    $h{$k = $x} = [];
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%h;
```

Note that this method considers everything that is not an assignment to be a scope marker.

The resulting data structure is suitable for feeding into something else. Using `{key => $key, 'value' => $value}` instead of `{$key => $value}` allows 1) straightforward handling of assignments in a scope upstream; and 2) actually allows the same identifier to be assigned multiple times in a scope (giving you an opportunity to detect this if so desired):

```
$VAR1 = {
          '<cell>' => [
                        {
                          'value' => 'cell2',
                          'key' => 'cell1'
                        }
                      ],
          '<pin>' => [
                       {
                         'value' => 'pin2',
                         'key' => 'pin1'
                       },
                       {
                         'value' => 'pin4',
                         'key' => 'pin3'
                       }
                     ],
          '<type>' => [
                        {
                          'key' => 'type1',
                          'value' => 'type2'
                        }
                      ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to split the $pattern into an array where each tag starts a new row.  This makes it easier to extract the relevant data as this example shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$pattern="<cell> cell1=1234567890 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2";
%cell=%pin=%type=();

print "Original pattern =$pattern\n";

($pattern_split=$pattern) =~ s/</\n</g;
@array=split(/\n/, $pattern_split);

# Extract relevant data (NOTE: finetune regex here) and store them in appropriate hashes indexed by $cnum (cellphone number)
for $_ (@array) {
  /<cell>\s*\w+=(\w+)/ && do { $cnum = $1; $cell{$cnum} = $cnum };
  /<pin>\s*(.+?)\s*$/ && do { $pin_list=$1; $pin{$cnum} = $pin_list };
  /<type>\s*\w+=(\w+)/ && do { $type{$cnum} = $1 };
}

$cn="1234567890";
print "Result: Cellnumber '$cell{$cn}' has pin_list='$pin{$cn}' and type='$type{$cn}'\n";
```

Prints:

```
Original pattern =<cell> cell1=1234567890 <pin> pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4 <type> type1=type2
Result: Cellnumber '1234567890' has pin_list='pin1=pin2 pin3=pin4' and type='type2'
```