# Simplify regex for capturing repeated sub groups

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to simplify this regex and still capture all groups?

```
my $str = "1 2 3 4 ;";
$str =~ /(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+/;
print Dumper( [$1, $2, $3, $4] );
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3',
          '4'
        ];
```

I tried using a quantifier to simplify:

```
$str =~ /(?:(\d+)\s+){4}/;
```

but it gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '4',
          undef,
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

Comment: The first regex looks as simple and straight forward as it gets. In which way should it be simpler? Simpler to scale to more groups? Simpler to read? Simpler to maintain? Consider looking at the definition of the tag "optimization".

Comment: Simpler to scale to N groups

Comment: I recommend to clarify that by [edit]ing your question. Consider showing the cases for 5 and 6 groups as example to help with visualising your problem.

Comment: Just `\d+` would have 4 matches isntead of actual groups... that's maybe even simplest?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785822/how-do-i-grab-an-unknown-number-of-captures-from-a-pattern/62786052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `/g` to match all numbers.

```
my @matches = $str =~ /\d+/g
```

Alternatively, [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#split-%2fPATTERN%2f%2cEXPR%2cLIMIT) on whitespace and [filter](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#grep-BLOCK-LIST) for numbers.

```
grep /\d+/, split /\s+/, $str;
```

---

`$str =~ /(?:(\d+)\s+){4}/;` does not work because while `{4}` causes it to match all four instances of `\d+\s+`, it does not change that there is only a single capture group.

Comment: May be useful  `/\b\d+\b/`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the groups by number, you would have to create them all as you did.

Using `(?:(\d+)\s+){4}` will repeat the outer group 4 times, capturing only the value of the last iteration in group 1.

---

One option could be to use `\G` to get all the digits in group 1.

```
\G(\d+)\h+(?=[\d\h]*;)
```

**Explanation**

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start
- `(\d+)\h+` Capture group 1, capture 1+ digits and match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[\d\h]*;` Match 0+ times a digit or horizontal whitespace char and ;
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH65Z0/1)

For example

```
my $str = "1 2 3 4 ;";
while ($str =~ /\G(\d+)\h+(?=[\d\h]*;)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: You mean like this `$str =~ /\G(\d+)\h+(?=[\d\h]*;)/g` ? It does not work

Comment: @HåkonHægland I think like this https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@3UkGluKRIwVZByVDBSMFYwUTBWsmaqzwjMydVQQMiVaegH@OuEZOirRmToa1hbxsdkxKTEatlramfrqlQzcVZUJSZV6KgpGIYkwfUWsvF9f8/AA